# What is the difference between travel and travelling?

Tags: differences

I would like to ask whether someone can explain the exact difference between 'travel' and 'travelling' to me. Some dictionaries say that travelling is an adjective but other dictionaries say that travelling could be a noun, too. I have not found any answers regarding my question yet, so it would be great if someone can help me here.

Comment: The form *travelling* (or *traveling* in AmE) is a form of the verb *travel* that can function as a gerund, which has many of the same syntactic functions as a noun. For instance, it can be the direct object of verb, as in "I like travel(l)ing." I do not think there is much of any difference in meaning between that and "I like travel." Subject, object of preposition, with or without determiners of various types--these syntactic roles too are open to both forms, the gerund *travel(l)ing* and the abstract noun *travel,* and I cannot think of one in which meaning really differs between them.

Answer (score 2):

*Traveling* is the present participial of the infinitive verb *to travel*. Particpials may take the form of a noun (gerund), a verb, an adjective, or an adverb(ial phrase). At its core, it is still a verb. Although somebody on this site is going to disagree, here are a few examples:

*Traveling is fun.* As the subject, I would call *traveling* a gerund, and thus, a noun.

*Are we traveling to Spain?* This example shows *traveling* as the priciple verb to the auxiliary *are*.

*They are gone, traveling to the moon.* *[T]raveling to the moon is* an adverbial phrase; although *traveling* in and of itself is a verb.

*The traveling circus is coming to town next month.* Here, *traveling* is an adjective modifying *circus.*

American English spellings.

Answer (score -2):

*Travelling* could be a **noun** like in : "a forward travelling of the camera went to focus on the face of the actor" or " travelling (plural of travel) are fine to improve your leisure"

**Travelling = travels** or a special move of a camera in film making ; but it can also be an **adjective** or the present of the **verb** *to travel* : "We're travelling in Botswana till we go back to Jo'burg"

In US we have trip for travel ; in UK they have journey...